# show same form which was hidden before

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project, there are two forms `frmLogin` and `frmMain`. After successful login from `frmLogin` I am showing the `frmMain` form to the user by doing something like this:

In `frmLogin` form `button_click` event:

```
frmMain main = new frmMain();
main.Show();
this.Hide();
```

In `frmMain` when the user logs out I want to show the same `frmLogin` form (not the instance). How to do this?

I tried this code: (*creating another instance of `frmLogin` which I don't want*)

In `frmMain` form `button_click` event:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to log out?", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo).Equals(DialogResult.Yes))
{
    this.FormClosing -= frmMain_FormClosing;
    //
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
    p.Start();
    //
    this.Dispose();
}
```

I have also tried using `internal` specifier but no use.

EDIT: As a trainee, I am not allowed to use `Static` keyword and altering `program.cs`. If the above approach requires restricted methods (which I have mentioned) then please suggest me an alternate approach.

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005732/showing-a-hidden-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All what you have to do is assign login page as `owner of nextform to be opened`

In your login Page call following function where you want to open nextForm

```
void openNextForm()
{
    Form f2 = new YourForm();    
    f2.owner=this;
    f2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

In your nextForm (e.g mainForm) write following aginst your button click

```
void ButtonLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Owner.Show();
     this.Hide();
     this.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: But the point is why would you write so much extra code when you can simple use the `ShowDialog()` method? Doesn't make sense. `ShowDialog()` even allows you to set the parent in the function call itself, without writing extra code.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro I asked a question which was not worthy (which I realized later after seeing your answer), but to make it worthy I gave it some limitations.

Comment: Yes @AbijeetPatro. You might have seen earlier I had shared this code earlier  `Form f2 = new YourForm();
f2.Shown += (s, e) => { f1.Hide(); };
f2.ShowDialog();
f1.Show();`

But he had little different query i.e. to show loginform only on logout of nextform and not on close. SO i had to edit

Answer (score 4):

Pass a frmLogin reference to frmMain. Then, just before you dispose of frmMain, show frmLogin.

```
frmMain main = new frmMain();
main.LoginForm = this;
main.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Then in the button click event:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to log out?", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo).Equals(DialogResult.Yes))
{
    this.FormClosing -= frmMain_FormClosing;
    LoginForm.Show();
    this.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I think you are missing something related to  `LoginForm`, VS is showing red scribbles.

Comment: Assuming your class names are MyLoginForm and MyMainForm, you'd need definitions in MyMainForm like this: `private MyLoginForm _loginForm; public MyLoginForm LoginForm { get { return _loginForm; } set { _loginForm = value; }}` or something like that (I don't have a code editor open at present.

Comment: +1 this is working but unfortunately big code compare to @Sami answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I upvoted Sami's answer because it's cleaner :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest approach when dealing with multiple forms is to create them in Program.cs, and keep all the methods to manage them there, then call those methods from event handlers. Kind of like this:

```
static class Program
{
    public static MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
    public static LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        mainForm.Hide();
        loginForm.Hide();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(loginForm);
    }

    public static void Login()
    {
        loginForm.Hide();
        mainForm.Show();
        // probably do more here
    }

    public static void Logout()
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to log out?", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo).Equals(DialogResult.Yes)))
        {
            mainForm.Hide();
            loginForm.Show();
            // probably do more here
        } 
    }
}
```

Then in event handlers you can just call Program.Login() or Program.Logout()

Comment: thank you for response, this is good but I cant use this. I should have mentioned before, please check my edited question.

Comment: you should convince them to let you, because creating forms inside forms and then passing references can get really confusing and error prone, after all did they hire you to write good or hacky code? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you don't use the ShowDialog() method?

```
 frmMain main = new frmMain();
 this.Hide();
 main.ShowDialog();
 this.Show();
```

The login form will be hidden and after the main form is closed, the login form's execution will continue and it will be automatically shown...

Comment: yes this is working, good logic but what if I want to use show() instead showDialog(). Just curious about it.