# Open a new form using button in C#

Tags: c#, android-activity

Hi i'm doing a simple activity in c# . i want to open a new form2 using a button and the form1 will automatically close when i press that button  .Here's My code:

```
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
```

Now i don't have idea What method will i use to close automatically the form1. Thank you..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226393/show-same-form-which-was-hidden-before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `this.Close();` use `this.Hide()` and on formclosing event of `Form2` give  `form1.Show()`.

for more information go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13226393/1577396) (I asked this question before).

Answer (score 4):

Wont work because the code control will halt on `form2.ShowDialog();`.

You will have to show form2 in a non-modal fashion:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
this.Close();
```

Or I guess you could fake it by hiding the form:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
this.Visible = false;
form2.Show();
this.Visible = true;
```

Try both versions to see which is better in your situation. Calling `ShowDialog();` will show the form as Modal causing all user mouse/keyboard input to be limited to form2 until you close it.

**Edit:** The Form2 must be declared as a member variable, it will go out of scope if it is decalred in the button event.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Visible = false;
form2.Show();
this.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: If you want to close it off completely, use the code 1 above.

Comment: @Jeremy sir when i use the first code. the two form is automatically closing.?