# C# - Combobox update on form show

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, combobox

For the start I am using **Sql Server Local DB** and **Linq to Sql**. I have two forms Form1 and Form2. There is a comboBox in Form1 that i want to update everytime it is shown. Form2 inserts new record and Form1 is for searching the record. After inserting a record when i go back to Form1. It doesnot update the list.
I have tried **Shown** and **Activated** for Form1 and **onClosing** event for Form2 but to no luck.
Also I have tried **Enter** event for comboBox. Though Database is updated but comboBox is not.
That is how i update my comboBox

```
_Namelist.Clear();
_Namelist.Add("Select a Name");
_Namelist.AddRange((from p in context.Peoples
                          select p.Name).ToList());
comboBox1.DataSource = _Namelist;
```

I have created a separate [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005732/showing-a-hidden-form) to make my main form that is FORM1 to be singleton.
To show Form1 i have used this

```
FormProvider.Form_1.Show();
```

In this scenario how can i update my comboBox?

**Update_1**

If I try to search (in Form1) the new data that i have inserted (in Form2) then it finds the record perfectly, just not updating comboBox.

**Update_2**

I just made a new Class

```
public class Database
{
    static DataContext context;

    public static List<string> getNames()
    {
        context = new DataContext();
        List<string> _names = new List<string>();

        _names.Add("Select a Name");
        _names.AddRange((from p in context.People
                                   select p.Name).ToList());

        return _names;
    }

}
```

Calling this function in any Event call of Form1 is doing the job. Can anyone tell me why it didn't work in the scenario i have described above in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that it could be related to data caching in LINQ.
Did you try [refreshing the DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.refresh.aspx) or flushing after creating the new record in Form2?

Comment: how to refresh data contex

Comment: See my updated my post, it now includes a hyperlink to the `Refresh()` method.

Comment: ! What should i place as OBJECT. is it the DATACONTEXT?

Comment: After the Update_1 in your post the problem does not seem to be the DataContext. You write that Form1 finds the new record then. So do I see it correctly that your method `getNames()` is just not called? Did you debug into it? If this is the problem then the solution which heathesh posted should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make the method to update the combo box on Form1 public, then on the close event of Form2 call the method:

So on Form1:

```
public void PopulateNamelistComboBox()
{
    _Namelist.Clear();
    _Namelist.Add("Select a Name");
    _Namelist.AddRange((from p in context.Peoples
                      select p.Name).ToList());
    comboBox1.DataSource = _Namelist;
}
```

Then on Form2 in the constructor, add the event handler to call the close event:

```
public Form2()
{
    Closed += Form2_Closed;
}
```

Then add the method on Form2:

```
private void Form2_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormProvider.Form_1.PopulateNamelistComboBox();
}
```

Comment: This is not solving the problem either. Unless i restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

You must Try Delegate: I am pasting URL for working project related your Scenario

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B893d39kVeIvcGhjUG80ZG05OWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I didn't get what were you were trying to teach me. Sorry, can you elaborate what to see exactly in your app?

Comment: Here i have attached C# project for updating gridview from another form's button w/o closing any form..just download project from link and check...even if you dont get, i could paste code here..