# Hide and unhide one form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have two form: Form1 and Form2. Both of it already have data.

- After I scan barcode in Form1, Form1 will be hidden, Form2 will show and somethings.
- After Form2 finish, Form1 will show again and Form2 will be hidden.

It's cycle.

I tried with:

```
///In Form1
Frm2 Form2 = new Frm2();
Form2.show();
this.Hide();

///In Form2
Frm1 Form1 = new Frm1();
Form1.show();
this.Hide();
```

But I think it make a new form with no data. So, how can I unhide form1 in form2?

Comment: You're creating new instances of both `Frm1` and `Frm2` every time, do this only once. Also how are you calling this code, please update your post to include further details about implementation. Also FWIW take a look at [Application.OpenForms Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=net-5.0) which will return all of the opened forms owned by your application.

Comment: Use Form1.Visible = true (or false).

Comment: You have to add a property on each form to keep a reference of the other Form and call Show on the property instead of creating a new Form (as you do). Using Application.OpenForms could help you too as said by Codexer.

Comment: Does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005732/showing-a-hidden-form

Comment: @amitklein thanks god. Love you <3

Comment: but how can we call one hidden form from other form. It's mean: call form1 show from form 2?

Comment: Why do you need to hide and not close it? if you need some data you can pass it through

Comment: @amitklein i only want unhide it again. after this.hide(). But from other form

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad, to call is just pass the instance of the class (form) to the second form and use it there

Comment: @amitklein can you give code for example. I'm beginer.

Comment: This should help you https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/834980/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-other-form-in-windows-form/

Comment: @amitklein it can transfer data beetween form. I think my situation very difference. It's raise oen action from other form